# Php app hangs session. Webserver restart fixes it.

Tags: php, apache, cacti

Running cacti on CentOS 5.6.
Every so often the browser hangs indefinitely (throbber spinning, no activity). The only (quick) way out (for the session) is restarting the webserver (kill the browser login again is actually longer in my setup).

All parameters are standard.

Advice, anyone?

Comment: have you checked your server logs? monitor what happens at the time when the server seems to hang and report back

Comment: As it turned out, the webserver (apache) wasn't complaining at all. However, it was configured (God knows why) with KeepAlive off. Turning it on solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

The webserver was configured with KeepAlive Off. Setting KeepAlive on solves the issue.